# How to populate nodes of a TreeView? (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winapp

I have a SQL Server Compact Edition Database file, and I want to display all the tables on it as nodes into a TreeView control in my windows application.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to.

This is what I have now:

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + connString))
        {            
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Don't know what's next...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
var tv = new TreeView();
using(var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + connString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(conn,"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"))
{
   conn.Open();
   if(conn.State != ConnectionStatus.Open) return;
   cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
   using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while(rdr.Read())
      {
         tv.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(rdr.GetString(0));
      }
   }
}
```

you can get fancier with the node creation. Have a look at the various constructors to see what you want.

Comment: Sorry TreeNode. It's been a while since I used it! ;)